# Check if PDF is password protected HummusJS, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, hummus.js

Does anybody perhaps know, how I can check if a PDF is password protected by using HummusJS in NodeJS?  This check needs to be done when modifying a PDF.

I am struggling to find a solution online and in the documentation.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I got this working, thanks to HummusJS's author.

A parser object will be able to check if a PDF is encrypted or not.  To create a PDFReader object (parser object), you can use:

```
var pdfReader = hummus.createReader('./TestMaterials/XObjectContent.PDF');
```

But when trying to modify the PDF, you will get an exception that the file is busy (EBUSY).

The PDFWriter object, can actually return a PDFReader object that it is using:

```
var pdfReader = pdfWriter.getModifiedFileParser();
```

By using this pdfReader object, use the following to detect if it is password protected:

```
pdfReader.isEncrypted()
```

Ciao!